# How to get a configured attribute in Nashorn called method

Tags: java, nashorn

I need to configure some attribute in [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)- or  [ScriptContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptContext.html)-level, to be used in Java methods.

So, how to get a reference to that `ScriptContext` in order to retrieve the value?

Example: setting the attribute:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    engine.getContext().setAttribute("param1", "paramValue", ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    engine.put("MyWindow", engine.eval("Java.type(\"" + MyWindow.class.getName() + "\")"));
    engine.eval("print(new MyWindow().test());");
}
```

`MyWindow` implementation: how to get that attribute?

```
public class MyWindow {

    public String test() {
        // how to get 'param1' value here
        return "in test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you running eval twice? Just do it in one call: `"var MyWindow = Java.type(\"" + MyWindow.class.getName() + "\"); print(new MyWindow().test());"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it in:

```
engine.eval("print(new MyWindow().test(param1));");
//                                     ^^^^^^

//                 vvvvvvvvvvvvv
public String test(String param1) {
    // how to get 'param1' value here
    return "in test";
}
```

**Update**

If you have code with a call stack like `javaMethod1 -> JavaScript -> javaMethod2`, and you want a value from `javaMethod1` to be available to `javaMethod2`, *without* changing the JavaScript to pass it on, use a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Since your code is in `main` you could just use a `static` directly, but I'm assuming your context is more complex. The code below works even in multi-threaded contexts. The `ThreadLocal` can be stored anywhere, it just has to be static and available to both java methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyWindow.param1.set("paramValue");
    try {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        engine.eval("var MyWindow = Java.type(\"" + MyWindow.class.getName() + "\");" +
                    "print(new MyWindow().test());");
    } finally {
        MyWindow.param1.remove();
    }
}

public class MyWindow {
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> param1 = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public String test() {
        String value = param1.get();
        return "in test: param1 = " + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that mean I need to change all JavaScript invocations. Instead, I need to configure a global attribute and use it in only Java part.

Comment: If it is truly global, as in across all threads, then a `static` in some shared class will do.